# laravel mail internal server error 500 after putting online

Tags: php, email, laravel

my mail worked (and still works) perfectly on my localhost. Now ive put my project to a dedicated server. And now when i try to mail i get "internal server error 500" and nothing more of detail.

I kept the same details, and changed nothing.

When i create an error in mail mail template it gives there an error so it really loops trough the mail function.

some of my settings:

```
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 465,
'from' => array('address' => "myemail@gmail.com", 'name' => "my name"),
'encryption' => 'ssl',
```

etc...
now there is 1 setting that i dont know if it has to change:

```
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

and in my controller:

```
      Mail::send('emails.shop', $data, function($message) 
     {
         $message->to("anEmail@gmail.com", 'hi')->subject('Service formulier ');
    });
```

Someone knows whats wrong?
(if needed i can give some more details)

i have a password and username set, but just didnt put it here, and it works on localhost with the password and username

update:
tested with tls and port 587  and didnt work

update2:

the logs: 
[Wed Dec 03 19:24:52 2014] [error] [client 91.181.50.243] FastCGI: comm with server "/var/www/cgi-bin/php5-mywebsite-fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec), referer: “”mywebsite””
[Wed Dec 03 19:24:52 2014] [error] [client 91.181.50.243] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/var/www/cgi-bin/php5-mywebsite-fcgi", referer: “”mywebsite””

Comment: look in the web server error logs on the server, there might be more info on what is causing the 500 there.  If not  increase logging in your php script and try again.     Also are you using gmail to send mail (external smtp server) or are you trying to use sendmail locally on the server. (and you are missing a password, which is needed with gmail to relay)

Comment: From server, can you telnet to port 465 / 587 on smtp.gmail.com?

Comment: i added the logs that where created as an update, and had password included but just didnt post it here. And i dont have many rights on the server. Its not my server

Comment: well if you don't have access to server to debug this it will be way harder. basically the logs show that the php script is hanging, and it didn't return any data in 30 seconds, so fcgi gave up..  So it is possible that it is waiting for gmail to answer or the like. you can  try adding debugging statements (log to /tmp? or just maybe echo/print them if you can get access to /tmp.

Comment: sorry if i sound noobish, i dont know that much about servers etc (this is my first site where i did backend) But i commented stuff in and out and it hangs in my controller, its the  Mail::send('emails.shop', $data, function($message) , if i do this away it doesnt hang, and its not the callback line thats faulty. sendmail doesnt need to be installed/enabled or something on the server?

Comment: ok so mail::Send is hanging. here is where you are going to need to get the server people involved. since depending on where it is hosted, etc.  A common practice is to block outbound SMTP ports (especially on new/cheap accounts) as a way to mitigate spam problems.  So I would ask the server hosting people about sending outbound email and see if they have any blocks in place

Comment: thanks, this worked! they blocked the port. If you put it as a answer, i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so mail::Send is hanging. here is where you are going to need to get the server people involved. since depending on where it is hosted, etc. A common practice is to block outbound SMTP ports (especially on new/cheap accounts) as a way to mitigate spam problems. So I would ask the server hosting people about sending outbound email and see if they have any blocks in place

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with **tls** ? And also try with port **587**. And it looks like you are missing password.